# How do I send key/value pairs to a web service with Python/SUDS?

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm trying to access a really simple SOAP web service via Python script using the SUDS library.

Here's the WSDL body:

[image: sample wsdl]

The python code I'm using to submit these two key/value pairs is as follows:

```
url = "http://somewhereontheweb.com/WS.asmx?wsdl"
client = suds.client.Client(url)

try:
    result = client.service.SendKDIRequest({"Key1": value1, "Key2": value2})    
    #display success
except Exception as e:  
    #display error
```

Entering them directly into the SoapUI client suggests that the service is working correctly. So I'm pretty sure I'm not sending through the key/value pairs as the web service expects them.

I'd really appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 2):

firstly you can use the logging methods of :

```
client.last_received()
client.last_sent()
```

these will output the xml suds is sending.

also if you print the client

```
print client
```

you will see if there are any complex types associated with the service, my guess is that KeyValue will be a type you will have to create using :

```
kv = client.factory.create("ns0:KeyValue")
```

that info should help you on your way.

Olly